# What exactly is this 'language' for my theory computation course saying?

Tags: notation, computer-science, formal-languages

In the manner of 2 + 2 telling me to add two and two together, what is this trying to say:

[image]

I'm not asking for an answer (I assume it's some sort of equation), just a starting place. Thanks a million.

Comment: It's set builder notation but I have no idea what it means. Normally the things on the right and left hand side of the dividing $\vert$ would be related somehow. Where did you find it?

Comment: @CyclotomicField It's part of the homework assignment given to us by our instructor; they teach theory computation. I'm guessing he made it off the top of his head. I'd ask, but I missed his office hours.

Comment: Are you sure you typed it correctly?  It's not $L = \{a^nb^mc^k\mid n≥k+m\}$ or something like that?  Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @MJD OP edited with a proper image. I used Word to convert the .pdf into something I could edit, and didn't bother to glance at the actual document beforehand. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

$L_1$ is a set of strings; such a set is called a “language”, hence the letter $L$.  (A string is a finite sequence of symbols.  “Symbol” is undefined.  Here you should understand that whatever a symbol is, `a`, `b`, and `c` are examples.)

The notation $\mathtt a^k\mathtt b^m\mathtt c^n$ means a string that has $k$ instances of `a`, followed by $m$ instances of `b`, followed by $n$ instances of `c`.  For example, $\mathtt a^3\mathtt b^1\mathtt c^8$  is a shorthand for the string `aaabcccccccc`.

The notation $$L_1 = \{\mathtt a^k\mathtt b^m\mathtt c^n\mid k+m+n\ge 2\}$$ means that $L_1$ is the set of all strings that have some `a`'s followed by some `b`'s followed by some `c`s, where the number of `a`'s plus the number of `b`'s plus the number of `c`'s is at least $2$.

For example, $L_1$ includes the string `aabbbc` because it can be understood as $\mathtt a^2\mathtt b^3\mathtt c^1$ and $2+3+1\ge 2$.  But the string `bbaabc` is not in $L_1$ because it doesn't have the `a`s before the `b`s before the `c`s.

Note that $k,m,$ and $n$ could be zero.  In particular, `bb` *is* in $L_1$ because it is $\mathtt a^0\mathtt b^2\mathtt c^0$ and $0+2+0\ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: Sure, I hope it was intelligible.  You're more likely to get good answers in the future if you can give us a clearer idea of what you already know.  Did I need to explain “string”?  Did I need to explain “set”?  No way for me to know from your question.